# How to solve TwinCAT XAR C++ module instance error?

Tags: twincat, twincat-ads, twincat-ads-.net

I have two PCs connected to each other in TwinCAT as shown in the picture.

Successful Connection
[image]

But, I am facing an error when I try to activate the configuration. Error AdsError 1792 is shown in the picture.
Error picture
[image: C++ module instance error]

For further reference, The compile outputs are added below.

Code Generation Output:
[image]

Code Publish Output
[image]
[image]
[image]

Code built Output
[image]

I was told to look in TcCOM but there was no subfolder in it. The Picture is added below.
TcCOM window
[image]

I hope this will help you understand the problem.

Comment: Did you do the preparations according to the documentation at Beckhoff for C++ development? https://infosys.beckhoff.com/english.php?content=../content/1033/tc3_c/260640651.html&id=5276784595576205301

Comment: Yes, the same program runs for the TwinCAT XAE on the engineering pc. But, it gives the error whenever I try to upload and run it on TwinCAT XAR in Run time PC.

Comment: Is your Run time PC in Windows Test Mode?
I see you are using a self signed testing certificate. To be able to use this kind of certificate your machine needs to be in Windows Test Mode

Comment: Yes, the runtime PC is in test mode as well.